# Confusion Over SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, security, simplemembership

I have a little confusion regarding the SimpleMembership and its use in a ASP.NET MVC Web site.

My project currently uses a code first dbcontext, which sits in a Class Library called "Data Access".

I have another class library called "DomainObjects" which includes all of my Entities/Objects which are used by the dbcontext declared in "Data Access".

I have another project called "DomainFactory" and as the name suggests, it exposes methods for accessing the data context, manipulating data etc etc.

And finally I have a MVC 4 Application called "Web" (this application actually uses IoC to call methods declared in the "DomainFacotry" project - however I don't believe this to be relevant to what I am trying to achieve here.)

My MVC application is now at a stage where I wish to add security to it.

Using the base Internet application template, I can see there is a UsersContext declared in the AccountModel.cs file, and this context is used heavily throughout the application.
This is not the behavior I want. For testability and separation of concerns, I want all my authentication logic to be handled by my Domain classes, however, I am not sure how to go about this, and would appreciate the following questions answered:

1. Because my MVC application has no reference to the dbcontext I have created, how can I regenerate and re-seed the database? Should I use WebActivator? Is this the preferred method?
2. What is the best way to move all authentication logic over to my DomainFactory project? If you have done this, how have you gone about it?
3. Is there anything I need to be aware of when using the method I have described above?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem here is having multiple contexts. EF doesn't play nice with multiple contexts and even if you get them to function, it's only possible to migrate one context at this time, so the others can merely reference existing DBOs.

Other than that, though, there's really nothing complicated about moving authentication into your class library. ASP nor EF care where your models live. As long as your DbContext can get a reference to them, you're good. In that regard, you *can* store the DbContext in a class library, as well, but just be advised that EF will only automatically see DbContext instances in startup projects. If you put it in a class library, you have to tell it to look there every time you `add-migration` or `update-database` with `-ProjectName 'MyClassLibrary'`.